# CKEDITOR 4 Disabling Snapshots

Tags: ckeditor

I'm implementing a CKEDITOR solution, and I don't need the CKEDITOR implementation of the undo stack.  The `saveSnapshot` event is getting fired, and it's affecting performance for large documents.  Is there any way to disable it, or prevent it from being fired in the first place?

Comment: I don't think that firing the event itself should affect performance, instead it's the Undo plugin that listens to that event the one that does a lot of work and so you should remove it from your editor if you don't need it.

Comment: AlfonsoML is 100% right. On the other hand I'm curious how is it possible that you don't need CKEditor's undo manager.

Comment: We've already removed the Undo plugin, and something else seems to be firing that event.  Are there other components that do the same?